# Pycharm Terminal Not Working

Tags: pycharm

I am trying type in Pycharm's terminal but it won't allow me to. I am using Pycharm 2018.1.4 (Community Edition) on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

[image]

Comment: can you provide more details? maybe a picture

Comment: i can't screenshot it because as I  click on the pycharm terminal the terminal window closes instantly

Comment: i fixed it from disappearing, but i cant type in the terminal. the terminal says -i PATH but im not sure what that means

Comment: can you send a screen shot of the terminal?

Comment: I added it to my question above

Comment: Have you checked the `Tools/Terminal` settings already?